# focus doesnt work on android

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile

I am building an application for android, using jquery mobile (windows 7). 
i have a function focus and using this function for example: you have a text field, and you want the text field to only accept numbers, and if you put in any string values an error will appear. 
The problem is that when I run the app on mobile the focus function doesnt work. (it works, if you give it an string an error will appear, but then you cant click on other fields, and when you click on same field the error message won go away you have to remove it manually) but when I run the same code in my local host it works just fine.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code in question, error output, console output?

Comment: I was sort of able to fix the problem. I just changed .focus to .click and it just worked!

Comment: You should add that solution as your answer so other people can see there is one when they are searching for the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the autofocus and pattern attributes available in html5.
autofocus is simple enough in that the field its on will get the focus on page load and pattern allows you to specify a regex that this particular field must adhere to.
http://html5pattern.com/